# Mathematica How do I plot a vector field with 1 variable?

Tags: vector, wolfram-mathematica, plot

I cannot figure out how to plot a vector field with only 1 variable. Maybe Mathematica doesn't support this. For example:

```
 r(t) = cost j + sint i
```

same as

```
 <cost, sint>
```

This doesn't work:

```
VectorPlot[{cos t, sin t}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

As a bonus how to take the derivative of a vector?

Comment: Are you aware that cosine of t is written as Cos[t] in Mathematica and not as cos t?

Comment: What do you mean by "vector field with one variable"?  Are you assigning a vector to each point of a link, and want to plot that vector *on* the line?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An easy workaround would be to use a 2D-`VectorPlot` with a dummy variable like this:

```
VectorPlot[
  {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {s, -1/2, 1/2},
  AspectRatio -> Automatic,
  VectorPoints -> {15, 3}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"t", None}
]
```

[image: VectorPlot with dummy variable]

Or what probably makes more sense is to discretize the curve that you get when you follow the vector while increasing `t`. This is e.g. useful for Feynman-style Action-integrals in quantum mechanics.

```
Module[
  {t, dt = 0.1, vectors, startpoints, startpoint, vector, spv, spvs},
  vectors = Table[dt {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi], dt}];
  startpoints = Accumulate[vectors];
  spvs = Transpose[{startpoints, vectors}];
  Graphics[Table[Arrow[{spv[[1]], spv[[1]] + spv[[2]]}], {spv, spvs}]]
]
```

[image: Feynman 1D-vectorplot]